# Javascript - Show element when scrolling inside div and each item of an array reaches top

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, addeventlistener

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to make a div with a scrollbar containing some items of an array inside.

When the user scrolls and each item reaches top it should display an element that is initially hidden.

This is what I have so far.

```js
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");

var i = 0;
var breakpoint = 100;                     

Array.from(articles).forEach(v => v.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var scrollDown = document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollDown >= breakpoint) {
       this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].classList.toggle('showdiv');
      }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px !important;
  background-color: salmon;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
}
.show-more {
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.showdiv {
  display: block !important;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 1</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 2</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 3</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 4</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 4</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 5</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 5</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 6</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 6</div>
    </div>
    <div>7
      <div class="content">content 7</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 7</div>7
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 8</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 8</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">content 9</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 9</div>
    </div><div>
      <div class="content">content 10</div>
      <div class="show-more">if this is on top, show content 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that if the user scrolls 100px, the function adds a class to show the div.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Intersection Observer API.